# Wordpress if/else causing error

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

The following code is not working and I'm not sure why. The idea is to have a text version of the logo on the home page. And and image version on all other pages. I copied the code from the WordPress codex. So I'm at a bit of a loss. Cheers.

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) {
<h1>Title</h1>
} else { <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/imageurl/image.png" alt="Logo" id="logo"/>
} ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate `php` and `html` properly here:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
<h1>Title</h1>
<?php
} else { ?>
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/imageurl/image.png" alt="Logo" id="logo"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly quick response. :) Worked perfectly

Comment: I tried but says I have to wait 15 minutes before I could. Hopefully should be done by now.